loading animation after submiting contact form google sheet
**Here is what worked **

i tryed to show loading animation during timedelay between after submiting form and showing success message(i am using swal.fire()to show success message) in my appscript just within index.html . but didn't worked.

here is what i successfully wrote code for loading animation
its working in standalone, i unable to add this loading animation feature in appscript index.html.
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myform").on("submit", function(){
    $("#preloder").fadeIn();
  });//submit
});//document ready

/* Preloder */

#preloder {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 999999;
    /* background: #000; */
    background: #ffffff;
}

.loader {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -20px;
    margin-left: -20px;
    border-radius: 60px;
    animation: loader 0.8s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation: loader 0.8s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes loader {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
        border: 4px solid #056d4d;      
        /* border: 4px solid #f44336; */
        border-left-color: transparent;
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
        transform: rotate(180deg);
        border: 4px solid #056d4d;
        /* border: 4px solid #673ab7; */
        border-left-color: transparent;
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
        border: 4px solid #056d4d;
        border-left-color: transparent;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes loader {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        border: 4px solid #056d4d;
        border-left-color: transparent;
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
        border: 4px solid #056d4d;
        border-left-color: transparent;
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        border: 4px solid #056d4d;
        border-left-color: transparent;
    }
}

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Page Preloder -->
<div id="preloder">
    <div class="loader"></div>
</div>

<form id="myform">
  <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" value="" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

Here is appscript i tryed to add timedelay loading animation feature. {files made in appscript: (code.gs and index.html and library id)}.
library id
1CcBYkrGSeBRgphHUE92vWInyULOcJ1Ub6eFUR0_gI1h9I6whLjXtDA-P
code.gs
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index').evaluate()
  .addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
  .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL)
}

var url = '#'
var sh = 'file1'
var folderId = '#'

function processForm(formdata) {
  var superscript = SuperScript.initSuper(url, sh);
  var formObject = {};
  formdata.forEach(element => formObject[element.name] = element.value);
  formdata.forEach(element => formObject[element.message] = element.value);
  formdata.forEach(element => formObject[element.email] = element.value);
  formdata.forEach(element => formObject[element.phone] = element.value);

  var f = formdata.find(({ name }) => name == "myfile");
  var file = (f && f.value?.name && f.value?.data) ? superscript.uploadFile(folderId, formObject.myfile.data, formObject.myfilename) : "";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheets()[0];
  ws.appendRow([
    new Date(),
    formObject.name,
    "'" + formObject.message,
    formObject.email,
    formObject.phone,
    file && file.getUrl()
  ]);

}



index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"
        integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ=="
        crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
  
  
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container py-5">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-8 mx-auto shadow border bg-white p-4 rounded">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-primary">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" fw-bold mb-3>WRITE YOUR QUERY / MESSAGE</a>
                </nav>
                <br>
                <form id="myForm" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit()">
                    <div id="form_alerts"></div>
                    <div class="form-group mb-3">
                        <label for="name">Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter your Name here|" name="name"required>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group mb-3">
            <label for="email" >Email</label>
                        <input type="email"  class="form-control" id="email"
            placeholder="Enter your email address here|" name="email" required>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group mb-3">
           <label for="phone">phone number</label>
  <input type="tel" id="phone" class="form-control" name="phone" placeholder="Enter your phone number here with country code|" pattern="[+]{1}[0-9]{2}[0-9]{10}" required>
  <small>requested example Format: +919263943858</small>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group mb-3">
              <label for="message">Message</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="message" placeholder="Write your message here|" name="message" required ></textarea>
              </div>

                         <div class="form-group mb-3">
                            <label for="uploadFile">Upload File</label>
                            <input type="file" class="form-control" File="file" id="file">
              <small>For multiple/bigger file size please attach/share via google drive link in message section.</small>
                            </div>

                            <button type="submit" class= "btn btn-primary btn-block">SEND</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  <script>
        function preventFormSubmit() {
                var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
                for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
                    forms[i].addEventListener('submit',
                     function (event) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                    });
                }
            }
            window.addEventListener('load', preventFormSubmit);
            function handleFormSubmit() {
                var formdata = $('#myForm').serializeArray()
                formdata.push({
                  name: 'myfile',
                  value: myfile
                })
                google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(success).processForm(formdata);
            }
            function success(){
                 document.getElementById("myForm").reset()
                 Swal.fire({
                  position: 'center',
                  icon: 'success',
                  title: 'Sended successfully! Be ready we will contact you shortly',
                  showConfirmButton: true,
      
                })
            }
        var myfile ={},file, reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onloadend = function(e) {
          myfile.data = e.target.result
          myfile.name = file.name
          console.log(myfile)
      };
     $('#file').change(function(){
       file = $('#file')[0].files[0]
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
     })
    </script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
  <script src="sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>


I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. What are the scripts before and after the line of Here is appscript i tryed to add timedelay loading animation feature. {files made in appscript: (code.gs and index.html and library id)}., respectively? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

i am saying that the when submit button is clicked the time taking to show success message looks like page stuck so i wanted to show loading animation until success message show up.

@tanaike  , hi , can you able to include this all css and code into index.html that i created in appscript, i tryed to make seperate css.html but didnt worked

below answered code almost worked(i include all css and code in index.html) but after clicking send button the loading animation spining forever not showing success message.

@Tanaike  hi here is what i tryed from below answered code it almost worked but after clicking submit the loading animaiton spining forever not showing success message but data getting successfully storing in sheet: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1RdOQwv7VPUVSbvJ4Jk4tTX3G9R-5t9PvBrtW_4axTR8/edit?usp=sharing

Modifying CSS using HTML DOM Document getElementById()
Use document.getElementById() to modify the CSS Element, Add your full style and attach it to the head element.

Modify the #Preloader Id Style:
Modify your function handFormSubmit() and call the CSS ID of #preloder and change the display from none to block to show the #preloder.
        function handleFormSubmit() {
          document.getElementById('preloder').style.display="block";
          var formdata = $('#myForm').serializeArray()
          formdata.push({
            name: 'myfile',
            value: myfile
          })
          google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(success).processForm(formdata);
          document.getElementById("myForm").reset()
        }

To return it to display: none; modify your function success() and then change the display to none.
function success(){
 Swal.fire({
  position: 'center',
  icon: 'success',
  title: 'Sended successfully! Be ready we will contact you shortly',
  showConfirmButton: true
 })
 document.getElementById('preloder').style.display="none";
}

Whole Html Code index.html:


<!DOCTYPE html>
    
    <head>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"
        integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ=="
        crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
      <style>
        /* Preloder */
    
        #preloder {
          display: none;
          position: fixed;
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
          top: 0;
          left: 0;
          z-index: 999999;
          /* background: #000; */
          background: #ffffff;
        }
    
        .loader {
          width: 50px;
          height: 50px;
          position: absolute;
          top: 50%;
          left: 50%;
          margin-top: -20px;
          margin-left: -20px;
          border-radius: 60px;
          animation: loader 0.8s linear infinite;
          -webkit-animation: loader 0.8s linear infinite;
        }
    
        @keyframes loader {
          0% {
            -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
            transform: rotate(0deg);
            border: 4px solid #056d4d;
            /* border: 4px solid #f44336; */
            border-left-color: transparent;
          }
    
          50% {
            -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
            transform: rotate(180deg);
            border: 4px solid #056d4d;
            /* border: 4px solid #673ab7; */
            border-left-color: transparent;
          }
    
          100% {
            -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
            transform: rotate(360deg);
            border: 4px solid #056d4d;
            border-left-color: transparent;
          }
        }
    
        @-webkit-keyframes loader {
          0% {
            -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
            border: 4px solid #056d4d;
            border-left-color: transparent;
          }
    
          50% {
            -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
            border: 4px solid #056d4d;
            border-left-color: transparent;
          }
    
          100% {
            -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
            border: 4px solid #056d4d;
            border-left-color: transparent;
          }
        }
      </style>
    
    </head>
    
    <body>
      <div class="container py-5">
        <div class="row">
          <div id="preloder">
            <div class="loader"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-8 mx-auto shadow border bg-white p-4 rounded">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-primary">
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" fw-bold mb-3>WRITE YOUR QUERY / MESSAGE</a>
            </nav>
            <br>
            <form id="myForm" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit()">
              <div id="form_alerts"></div>
              <div class="form-group mb-3">
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter your Name here|" name="name"required>
              </div>
    
              <div class="form-group mb-3">
                <label for="email" >Email</label>
                <input type="email"  class="form-control" id="email"
                placeholder="Enter your email address here|" name="email" required>
              </div>
    
              <div class="form-group mb-3">
                <label for="phone">phone number</label>
                <input type="tel" id="phone" class="form-control" name="phone" placeholder="Enter your phone number here with country code|" pattern="[+]{1}[0-9]{2}[0-9]{10}" required>
                <small>requested example Format: +919263943858</small>
              </div>
    
              <div class="form-group mb-3">
                <label for="message">Message</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" id="message" placeholder="Write your message here|" name="message" required ></textarea>
              </div>
    
              <div class="form-group mb-3">
                <label for="uploadFile">Upload File</label>
                <input type="file" class="form-control" File="file" id="file">
                <small>For multiple/bigger file size please attach/share via google drive link in message section.</small>
              </div>
    
              <button type="submit" class= "btn btn-primary btn-block">SEND</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      <script>
        function preventFormSubmit() {
                var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
                for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
                    forms[i].addEventListener('submit',
                      function (event) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        
                    });
                }
            }
                window.addEventListener('load', preventFormSubmit);
    
            function handleFormSubmit() {
              document.getElementById('preloder').style.display="block";
              
              var formdata = $('#myForm').serializeArray()
              formdata.push({
                name: 'myfile',
                value: myfile
              })
              google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(success).processForm(formdata);
              document.getElementById("myForm").reset()
            }
                function success(){
                  Swal.fire({
                  position: 'center',
                  icon: 'success',
                  title: 'Sended successfully! Be ready we will contact you shortly',
                  showConfirmButton: true
                  })
                  document.getElementById('preloder').style.display="none";
                }
            var myfile ={},file, reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onloadend = function(e) {
              myfile.data = e.target.result
              myfile.name = file.name
              console.log(myfile)
          };
         $('#file').change(function(){
           file = $('#file')[0].files[0]
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
         })
      </script>
    
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
      <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
      <script src="sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
    </body>
    
    </html>




Sample Output:

Reference:

HTML DOM Document getElementById()


Wow! It worked but little issue..data not getting visible in sheet.
(https://drive.google.com/file/d/17U-xR_5iasX-JYUe0btqeXHMsyQBWSPp/view?usp=sharing)
Even not in emails
Attempt 1:  When form submitting without file non of data is visible(like name,email,phone,message,file). (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1r6VHLTQEKV8ZFng-9sc4PFI9UAMNwIhM/view?usp=sharing)
Attemp 2: when form submitting with file the only file data is visible rest (name,email,phone,message) are not visible.
(https://drive.google.com/file/d/168KhpqmfrGXL9AlxJ5QQpg9zSPyZRkZn/view?usp=sharing)

have you tried putting all the rest of the code together? @ankit

yes i tryed but didnt worked.

sorry there was a misplaced line of code. I got the solution for this.

I already updated my answer.
can you try this:
function handleFormSubmit({document.getElementById('preloder').style.display="block";var formdata = $('#myForm').serializeArray();formdata.push({name: 'myfile',value: myfile}); google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(success).processForm(formdata);document.getElementById("myForm").reset();}

nooo. now its not working nothing. after submitting showing blanck white screen nothing loading not data visible in sheet.

can you copy the whole Html index.html again?

awesommmmmmmm ,, amazing , alll worked . very talented,,,,best blesses with you .....

Have you tried activating the animation right before submitting? Also make sure you are preventing the default form submit behavior.
change to:
<form id="myForm" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(); return false">



function handleFormSubmit() {
  var formdata = $('#myForm').serializeArray()
  formdata.push({
    name: 'myfile',
    value: 12
  })

  // here
  $("#preloder").fadeIn();

  // just in case
  try {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(success).processForm(formdata);
  } catch (ex) {
    console.error(ex.message)
  }

}
/* Preloder */

#preloder {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 999999;
  /* background: #000; */
  background: #ffffff;
}

.loader {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -20px;
  margin-left: -20px;
  border-radius: 60px;
  animation: loader 0.8s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: loader 0.8s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes loader {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    border: 4px solid #056d4d;
    /* border: 4px solid #f44336; */
    border-left-color: transparent;
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    border: 4px solid #056d4d;
    /* border: 4px solid #673ab7; */
    border-left-color: transparent;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    border: 4px solid #056d4d;
    border-left-color: transparent;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes loader {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    border: 4px solid #056d4d;
    border-left-color: transparent;
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    border: 4px solid #056d4d;
    border-left-color: transparent;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    border: 4px solid #056d4d;
    border-left-color: transparent;
  }
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Page Preloder -->
<div id="preloder">
  <div class="loader"></div>
</div>

<form id="myform" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(); return false">
  <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" value="" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>




how to include this css in html

can you able to include this all css and code into index.html that i created in appscript, i tryed to make seperate css.html but didnt worked

hi, as your code worked but after clicking send button the loading animation spining forever not showing success message.

on the success callback for google, success, you should add there code like ("#preloder").fadeOut();

hi here is what i tryed it almost worked but after clicking submit the loading animaiton spining forever not showing success message but data geting successfully storing in sheet: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1RdOQwv7VPUVSbvJ4Jk4tTX3G9R-5t9PvBrtW_4axTR8/edit?usp=sharing
